# AMD jQuery Multiselect Widget

Tags: jquery, requirejs, jquery-ui-multiselect, requirejs-define

I'm trying to use `jQuery` [multi-select widget](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) with AMD and handlebars.
Here's the handlebars snippet:

```
{{#section 'js'}}
  <script type='text/javascript' nonce="{{nonce}}">
    requirejs([
      "domReady",
      "app/ui/js/utils/Chart.min",
      "app/ui/js/utils/jquery.multiselect",
      "app/ui/js/utils/jquery-ui.min",
      "app/ui/js/y",

    ],
    function(wrapper, domReady, x) {
      domReady(function() {
        $.when(wrapper.init()).then(
          function() {
            x.init();
          }
        );
      });
    });
  </script>
{{/section}}
```

Here are the contents of `y.js`:

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'app/ui/rest/x',
        'app/ui/js/utils/errorhandlingutils'
], function( $, restX, errorHandler ) {
    "use strict";
    function _init() {
        //Do something
    }
    return {
        init: function() {

            //Global Init function
            _init();
        }
    };
});
```

I want to use the multi-select widget in `y.js`. How should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `"jquery"` as a dependency in the handlebars snippet to resolve this.